# Jetty issue with getHeaders

Tags: java, apache, jetty

I've recently upgraded Apache WAMP on my local and now Jetty is having a problem with every request.

The issue is as below, but I don't know enough about Jetty to work out what the problem is with getHeaders and can't find anything similar.

This only appears to happen when I'm trying to load JSON in the browser, i.e. PrimeFaces etc is loading correctly

Anyone help me debug this?

> Tue Oct 04 10:55:22 NZDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection
>   without server's identity verification is not recommended. According
>   to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must
>   be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification.

```
 HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /guide/362/json. Reason:

    org.mortbay.jetty.Response.getHeaders(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;
Caused by:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.mortbay.jetty.Response.getHeaders(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.get(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:161)
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.containsKey(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:262)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

POM.XML

Ahh I notice

[main] INFO org.mortbay.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
[main] INFO org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.x

When the app starts.. OK I'm using an old version of Jetty

Dependency tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:tree (default-cli) @ beek-admin ---
[INFO] artifact org.glassfish:javax.el: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact org.glassfish:javax.el: checking for updates from sonatype-snaps
hots
[INFO] co.beek:beek-admin:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail:jar:4.3.0.RELE
ASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.0.R
ELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compil
e
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile

[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Fin
al:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.10.77:compile

[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-events:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codepipeline:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directory:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-efs:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codecommit:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-devicefarm:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-waf:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics:jar:1.10.77
:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-inspector:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-gamelift:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dms:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacemeteringservice:jar:1.10.77:c
ompile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.77:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.5
.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:5.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces.extensions:all-themes:pom:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:afterdark:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:afternoon:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:afterwork:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:black-tie:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:blitzer:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:bluesky:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:bootstrap:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:casablanca:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:cruze:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:cupertino:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:dark-hive:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:dot-luv:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:eggplant:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:excite-bike:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:flick:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:glass-x:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:hot-sneaks:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:humanity:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:le-frog:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:midnight:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:mint-choc:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:overcast:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:pepper-grinder:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:redmond:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:rocket:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:sam:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:smoothness:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:south-street:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:start:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:sunny:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:swanky-purse:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:trontastic:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:ui-darkness:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:ui-lightness:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.primefaces.themes:vader:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.primefaces.themes:home:jar:1.0.8:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.3.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.M0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211
821:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.2.v20130121:co
mpile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-overlay-deployer:jar:9.1.0.M0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.1.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-spring:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.0.M0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:jar:0.97-incubator:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.flexjson:flexjson:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.charts4j:charts4j:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.gdata:core:jar:1.47.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:jar:1.11.0-beta:c
ompile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.11.0-bet
a:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compi
le
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:jar:v3-rev116-1.20.0:com
pile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:2.4.10-0.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:0.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.bytedeco:javacv:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:3.0.2-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:windows-x86_64:3.0.2-1.2
:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:2.9.3.43-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:windows-x86_64:2.9.3
.43-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:2.2.4-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:windows-x86_64:2.2.4-
1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:0.5.3-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:windows-x86_64:0.5.
3-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:0.200-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:windows-x86_64:0.200
-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:2.3.1-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:windows-x86_64:2.
3.1-1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:1.07-1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:windows-x86_64:1.07-1
.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2.1-b05:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2.1-b04:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided (scope not updated
to compile)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
```

I have this in my POM, sorry I didn't develop this I'm not entirely sure what's going on!

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jetty-classpath</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>org.mortbay.jetty,javax.servlet,org.slf4j</includeGroupIds>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>jsp-api,jstl</excludeArtifactIds>
                            <excludes>META-INF/ECLIPSEF.*</excludes>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: can we see list of jars you use or pom if your use maven ?

Comment: Thanks I added the pom (had to remove web.xml because post was too long)

Comment: looks like you are using multiple versions of javax.servlet-api. please mark the 3.0.1 version scope as provided too and also mark the javax.servlet.jsp-api scope as provided too.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that and it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: Seeing `org.mortbay.jetty` in your stacktraces means you are not using Jetty 9.x, but something much much older (circa Jetty 6.x or older)

Comment: Run `$ mvn dependency:tree` and include the results of that in your question please.

Comment: Thanks. Ahh I notice

[main] INFO org.mortbay.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog [main] INFO org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.x